# Shopify javascript api from a store's frontend

Tags: javascript, authentication, frontend, shopify

I made a scripttag (with a Rails app) for shopify, and there is few line code in it:

```
$.getJSON('/admin/custom_collections.json',function(res) {

    $(res.custom_collections).each(function(index,collection) {
        var collectionHTML = '<li><a data-collection-id="' + collection.id + '" href="#">' + collection.title + '</a></li>';
        $("#ajax-search-container").append(collectionHTML);
    })
})
```

Is it possible to use it from a store frontend? 
How can I authenticate this javascript to store admin?

Answer (score 0):

One of the mest method to authenticate the JS, is to send a access_token with the request. Or you can send a request to your server, and then check for the user had change anything, by create a method to MD5 validate the request.

But personal I use the first method where I send a token and check up on that. You can generate this token and store them insite a DB and let them have a life time. So if the user doesn't post in like 5 minutes, then the token is invalid.

**This is for generating the token**

```
before_filter :generate_token_to_db

private

def generate_token_to_db
  Token.create!(:token => generate_token)
end

def generate_token
  (0...64).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join
end
```

Then you may insite the admin site, search for this token, and then if it's there, do the action, and if not then redriect the customer and tell him about the fail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am a little confused, can you post some code? I send a token in request, but where I generate this token? And where is the authentication part on the server? In an Shopify App?

Comment: OK, thank you! I posted a code in my question, that is in the frontend of a store. Maybe there is a little misunderstanding here: if the store calls this javascript, the browsers shows a htaccess authentication window. That was my question how to authenticate it :)

Comment: Well I do not have a solution for that. I'm sorry